# Windows Authentication in IIS using Kestrel

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, kestrel-http-server

My web application needs windows authentication (Kerberos or NTLM) to manage authorization by Active Directory memberships.

I've configured my IIS web site with windows authentication only.

My web.config is configured with forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"

But how can I use my windows account in my C# MVC controllers?